# How do i fix my windows boot loader?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bootloader

Recently i've installed Kali linux on my computer and the idea was to run a dual boot with Win 10, however it didn't go as planned. I've used a software called EasyBcd, some of you might be familiar with this software. Basically under the boot list in EasyBcd I removed the main boot loader for windows and selected a new one for linux that I created. I rebooted and found out that I cannot boot linux like that. So now i've installed linux the right way but I cannot boot windows anymore. It seems like the boot loader cannot locate the C: partition where windows is installed. I have created a new store in Windows boot loader throgh cmd, so my main loader "default" is now pointet to Partition=C: This didn't help. I don't have a windows recovery usb/cd and don't really want to lose my data.

Conclusion: 
* Kali linux is working fine.
* Windows is not booting with a errorcode: 0c0000225

Just so you know I did google this last night. Where on google for like 5 hours with no result..
Hope someone can help me here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rebuild your mbr. To do this you need a windows installation disk. Boot from that disk and go to command prompt. In command prompt type:

`bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr`

this fixes boot record of partition mapped to "drive_letter:" and the MBR of the disk where the partition is placed.

```
C:\Windows\system32>bootsect

bootsect {/help|/nt60|/nt52} {SYS|ALL|<DriveLetter>:} [/force] [/mbr]

Boot sector restoration tool

Bootsect.exe updates the master boot code for hard disk partitions in order to
switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR.  You can use this tool to restore the boot
sector on your computer.

Run "bootsect /help" for detailed usage instructions.
```

Comment: I dont have the install disk, however i can get in to cmd by the new recovery system in windows(i think it came with win 8 and later versions) can i do this without the disk?

Comment: Yes you can! Just go to cmd in recovery mode and everything same as the answer.

Comment: thanks this command saved me after moving Windows to an SSD using DD in Linux to clone the installation, the other commands on windows fix mbr help pages could not find the path